# How to read office documents (docx, xlsx, pptx etc.) and display in cfm ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, apache-poi, document, coldfusion-10, file-conversion

I have read and tried the tutorial by [raymond camden](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2009/02/04/Reading-Office-documents-with-ColdFusion) to read office documents and display in cfm page. Since the tutorial was done few years back, it was only able to read doc, ppt and xls, instead of new ones which are docx, pptx, xlsx. How am I supposed to read the files successfully? Renaming the file extension does not work for Apache POI.

My code:

```
<!--- where the poi files are --->
<cfset jarpath = expandPath("./jars")>
<cfset paths = []>
<cfdirectory action="list" name="files" directory="#jarpath#" filter="*.jar" recurse="true">

<cfloop query="files">
<cfset arrayAppend(paths, directory & "/" & name)>
</cfloop>

<!--- load javaloader --->
<cfset variables.loader = createObject("component", "javaloader.JavaLoader").init(paths)>

<!--- generic file reader doohicky --->
<cfset myfile = createObject("java","java.io.FileInputStream")>

<!--- get our required things loaded --->

<!--- Word --->
<cfset doc = loader.create("org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument")>
<cfset wordext = loader.create("org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor")>

<!--- Excel --->
<cfset excel = loader.create("org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook")>
<cfset xlsext = loader.create("org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.ExcelExtractor")>

<!--- Powerpoint --->
<cfset ppt = loader.create("org.apache.poi.hslf.HSLFSlideShow")>
<cfset pptext = loader.create("org.apache.poi.hslf.extractor.PowerPointExtractor")>

<!--- get files --->
<cfset filePath = expandPath("./testdocs")>
<cfdirectory action="list" name="files" directory="#filePath#">

<cfoutput query="files">
<cfset theFile = filePath & "/" & name>
<cfset myfile.init(theFile)>

Reading: #theFile#<br/>

<cfswitch expression="#listLast(name,".")#">

<cfcase value="doc,docx">
<cfset finalfile = Replace(theFile, listLast(name,"."), "doc")>
<cfset doc = doc.init(finalfile)>
<cfset wordext.init(doc)>
<cfoutput>
<pre>
#wordext.getText()#
</pre>
</cfoutput>
</cfcase>

<cfcase value="xls,xlsx">
<cfset finalfile = Replace(theFile, listLast(name,"."), "xls")>
<cfset excel = excel.init(finalfile)>
<cfset xlsext = xlsext.init(excel)>
<cfoutput>
<pre>
#xlsext.getText()#
</pre>
</cfoutput>
</cfcase>

<cfcase value="ppt,pptx">
<cfset finalfile = Replace(theFile, listLast(name,"."), "ppt")>
<cfset ppt = ppt.init(finalfile)>
<cfset pptext = pptext.init(ppt)>
<cfoutput>
<pre>
#pptext.getText(true,true)#
</pre>
</cfoutput>
</cfcase>
</cfswitch>

<p><hr/></p>

</cfoutput>
```

These are the brief error's description:

```
Object instantiation exception.

An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class must not be an interface or an abstract class. Error: ''.

The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/TicketOnThePlane/test.cfm: line 66
64 : <cfcase value="ppt,pptx">
65 : <cfset finalfile = Replace(theFile, listLast(name,"."), "ppt")>
66 : <cfset ppt = ppt.init(finalfile)>
67 : <cfset pptext = pptext.init(ppt)>
68 : <cfoutput>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `<cfpresentation>` (https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfpresentation) ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the most recent POI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes you are using are only designed for binary office files ie Office 97-2003. Changing the file extension won't work because that does not actually modify the format of the files. They are still ooxml files internally.

If you want to extract the text from different file types (and both formats ie binary and ooxml), use the [`ExtractorFactory`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/extractor/ExtractorFactory.html). It will automatically determine the correct extractor for the given file (if supported). There is another entry that demonstrates [how to use the ExtractorFactory](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2009/02/05/Reading-Office-documents-with-ColdFusion-2) at the end of the link you posted.

**NB:** This requires the [OOXML POI jars](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)

```
....
loader = createObject("component", "javaloader.JavaLoader").init(paths);
extractorFactory = loader.create("org.apache.poi.extractor.ExtractorFactory");
pathToFile = "c:/path/to/someFile.xlsx";
myfile = createObject("java","java.io.File").init(pathToFile);
extractor = extractorFactory.createExtractor(myFile);
WriteDump( extractor.getText());
```

**Edit:**

> These are the brief error's description:

Side note, when using java objects, the error message text will typically just show you a boilerplate message. You need to look at the stack trace to get the true "cause" of the error.

Comment: Hi Leigh, When I am trying this I got this error "Error casting an object of type java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception to an incompatible type. This usually indicates a programming error in Java, although it could also mean you have tried to use a foreign object in a different way than it was designed. " now am using poi-ooxml-3.9.jar. Could you please take a look what I did wrong with this?